# How to extract values from C++ structure with bitfields

Tags: c++, bitmask

This is my problem, I have a structure (that I cannot change) like the following:

```
struct X
{
    uint8_t fieldAB;
    uint8_t fieldCDE;
    uint8_t fieldFGH;
    ...
}
```

Each field of this structure contains different values packed using a bitmask (bitfield), that is for example `fieldAB` contains two different values (A and B) in the hi/lo nibbles, while `fieldCDE` contains three different values (C, D and E with the following bit mask: bit 7-6, bit 5-4-3, bit 2-1-0) and so on...

I would like to write a simple API to read and write this value using *enum*, that allows to easily access to values of each field:

```
getValue(valueTypeEnum typeOfValue, X & data);
setValue(valueTypeEnum typeOfValue, X & data, uint8_t value);
```

Where the enum valueTypeEnum is something like this:

```
enum valueTypeEnum
{
    A,
    B,
    C,
    D,
    E,
    ...
}
```

My idea was to use a map (dictionary) that given valueTypeEnum returns the bitmask to use and the offset for access to the right field of the structure, but I think it's a little tricky and not so elegant.
What are your suggestions?

Comment: How about bitfields ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I cannot make any changes to the structure. I've updated the original post.

Comment: Why is there a C++ tag here? If you were using C++, use `std::bitset` to manipulate bits.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of a few ways this could be done, the simplest is to use bitfields directly in your struct:

```
struct X {
   uint32_t A : 4; // 4 bits for A. 
   uint32_t B : 4; 
   uint32_t C : 4; 
   uint32_t D : 4; 
   uint8_t E : 7; 
   uint8_t F : 1;
};
```

Then you can easily get or set the values using for instance:

```
X x;
x.A = 0xF;
```

Another way could be to encode it directly in macros or inline functions, but I guess what you are looking for is probably the bitfield.

As pointed out in the comments, the actual behaviour of bit-fields may depend on your platform, so if space is of the essence, you should check that it behaves as you expect. [Also see here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field) for more information on bit-fields in C++.

Comment: Downvoted because using any other type than 'int' certainly used to be unsupported for a bitfield in C, and the OP hasn't indicated which C compiler or standards flags are in use. The consequence is that this option may, or may not work depending on how and for what processor the code is compiled.

Comment: FWIW, I wish that Stian's version did work as you'd expect, and perhaps in the particular case of the OP it does. However, the C99 interpretation of fields E and F could be that they are not consecutive bytes, but in consecutive longwords.

Comment: I answered from a C++ point of view, as that was what the OP was tagged as. As far as I know, "most" C++ compilers does allow ubytes in bitsets. I would say a warning that on some platforms it may not work as expected is a better comment than *don't do this*.

Comment: This page: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/bit_field says that packing fields is implementation defined - which means a compiler is free to choose what it finds easiest to do. I accept though that C++ does permit byte containers. I'll un-downvote as a result.

Answer (score 1):

I'll dig into the bitfields a little more :

Your X structure is left unchanged :

```
struct X
{
    uint8_t fieldAB;
    uint8_t fieldCDE;
    uint8_t fieldFGH;
};
```

Let's define an union for easy translation :

```
union Xunion {
    X x;
    struct Fields { // Named in case you need to sizeof() it
        uint8_t A   : 4;
        uint8_t B   : 4;

        uint8_t C   : 2;
        uint8_t D   : 3;
        uint8_t E   : 3;

        uint8_t F   : 2;
        uint8_t G   : 3;
        uint8_t H   : 3;
    };
};
```

And now you can access these bitfields conveniently.

Before anyone tries to skin me alive, note that this is in no way portable, nor even defined by the C++ standard. But it'll do what you expect on any sane compiler.

You may want to add a compiler-specific packing directive (e.g GCC's `__attribute__((packed))`) to the `Fields` struct, as well as a `static_assert` ensuring the `sizeof` both union members are strictly equal.

Comment: definitely have a static assert. At least then you're warned if things go funky.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet IMO is to forget using a structure at all, or if so use a union of a structure and a byte array. Then have your access functions use the byte array, for which it's easy to calculate offsets and so on. Doing this you are I believe guaranteed to access the bytes you want.

The downside is that you will have to re-assemble 16 and 32 bit values, if any, found in the structure, and do so bearing in mind any endianness issues. If you know that any such values are found on 16 or 32 bit address boundaries, you could use union'd short and long arrays to do this which would probably be best, though somewhat opaque.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I found a solution.
I can create an API like the following:

```
uint8_t getValue(valueTypeEnum typeOfValue, X * data)
{
    uint8_t bitmask;
    uint8_t * field = getBitmaskAndFieldPtr(typeOfValue, data, &bitmask);

    return ((*field) & bitmask) >> ...;
}

void setValue(valueTypeEnum typeOfValue, X * data, uint8_t value)
{
    uint8_t bitmask;
    uint8_t * field = getBitmaskAndFieldPtr(typeOfValue, data, &bitmask);

    *field = ((*field) & !bitmask) | (value << ...);
}

uint8_t * getBitmaskAndFieldPtr(valueTypeEnum typeOfValue, X * data, uint8_t * bitmask)
{
    uint8_t * fieldPtr = 0;

    switch(typeOfValue)
    {
         case A:
         {
               *bitmask = 0x0F; // I can use also a dictionary here
               fieldPtr = &data.AB;
               break;
         }
         case B:
         {
               *bitmask = 0xF0; // I can use also a dictionary here
               fieldPtr = &data.AB;
               break;
         }
         case C:
         {
               *bitmask = 0xC0; // I can use also a dictionary here
               fieldPtr = &data.CDE;
               break;
         }
         ...    
    }

    return fieldPtr;
}
```

I know that the switch-case is not so elegant and require to be updated each time the structure is changed, but I don't see an *automatic* way (maybe using reflection) to solve this problem.

Comment: If you can't use the union solution from Quentin, I would be so tempted to write a group of function-pairs to get and set each item independently, mark them 'inline' and stick them in a header file. I wouldn't bother about trying to be generic about the calls (i.e. valueTypeEnum).